# Scrapy arguments in URL from table

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler

**Hello everyone!**

I am currently working on a Scrapy Webcrawler, using Python 2.7, and while I do know C and Web languages, I am a little lost with Python and the Scrapy Library.

What I wish to do is to crawl a single URL which returns JSON data, and to change the arguments in the URL according to a predefined table of arguments.

The URL looks like this:

> http://www.helloworld.com/data?From=*xxx*&To=*yyy*&number=*42*.

Here, I would like to replace all xxx, yyy, 42, from a set of data stored in a different file, and loop the crawler using each one of the parameters.

I know I could do :

```
    def __init__(self, fromdat='xxx', todat='yyy'):
    self.start_urls = ["http://helloworld.com/data?From=%s&To=%s/" % (fromdat, todat)]
```

and then specify the parameters using the -a command in the command line, but this would involve a human intervention, which I do not wish for.

I have also already tried :

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "histo"
tab1=[1000,10]

def start_requests(self, tab1):
    for i in tab1:
        urls = 'http://www.helloworld.com/data?number=%d'% i
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'histo-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick either...

I am a bit lost so any help is gladly welcome! :)

Thanks a lot in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The [`start_requests()`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) does not accept any additional arguments, do the following:

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "histo"
    tab1 = [1000,10]

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in self.tab1:
            urls = 'http://www.helloworld.com/data?number=%d' % i
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'histo-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Note how the `parse()` is indented.

Comment: Well thanks a lot, it indeed worked!
And yes sorry I have a bit of trouble concerning the indentation in Python, I am really not used to it, but after correcting it it works fine.
However I still have a little issue in the restitution of the data which was collected by the crawler: 

From your code, I just modified in "yield" the request from (url=url) to (url=urls) for my data to be scrapped. However, the data scraped is first written in a file and then overwritten with the data contained in the URL with the second argument. My wish is to consolidate all the data in one file..Thanks a lot

Comment: @M.C. okay, I think you mean to use the `a` mode instead of `wb`. Let me know it this is what you've meant. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your time, actually, using the 'a' mode instead of 'wb' in open(filename, 'wb'), doesn't change anything  (i am on Windows but project to run the spider on a Raspberry Pi). My code is suposed to write each of the extraction in separate html files, but data gets overwritten in the same file and I don't understand why.